# Why [[no_unique_address]] attribute doesn't work in some cases?

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm playing around with [[[no_unique_address]]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) attribute introduced in C++20. As far as I understood from [cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) and `dcl.attr.nouniqueaddr` chapter of the Standard, this attribute indicates that the field need not have an address distinct from all other non-static data members of the class. Therefore the compiler can optimize the memory layout of the struct. But there is one thing that confuses me.

Consider the following example (https://godbolt.org/z/fj6nGebcs):

```cpp
struct Empty {};
struct Test {
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty em1;
  char f1;
  int f2;
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty em2;
};
```

The field `em1` has a zero size and will be located at the same address as `f1`.
It seems logical to me that the same optimization could be applied to `em2` and it will have the same address as `f2` and zero size. But it doesn't work that way. After some experimentation, I can say that if a field with `[[no_unique_address]]` is defined at the end of the struct, this optimization won't work at all. So compiled with the latest versions of gcc and clang, the size of the `struct Test` will be 12 (1-byte `char` field, 3 bytes alignment, 4-byte `int` field, and `struct Empty` field with size 1 byte and 3 bytes alignment).

Now let's move the `em2` up (https://godbolt.org/z/Goz9Tj66K):

```cpp
struct Empty {};
struct Test {
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty em1;
  char f1;
  [[no_unique_address]] Empty em2;
  int f2;
};
```

After this change, the size of the `struct Test` will be 8, and `em2` field will have the same address as `f2`.

I don't understand why it works this way. I found the tests for the size of the same struct in [clang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/18cb17ce4cd54b9971550840b6f0b872de0d4c8c/clang/test/Layout/no-unique-address.cpp#L126-L134). And the latest gcc works in the same way.

But I'm not sure, why compilers can't apply `[[no_unique_address]]` optimization in the first example above like in the second one.
Are there any technical limitations? Or is it related to the internal implementation of compilers?

Comment: It is up to quality of implementation, they could do the same for both snippets.

Comment: _"...The field `em1` have a zero size..."_ - No - "_...The result of sizeof is __always nonzero__, even if applied to an empty class type...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: They followed the same ABI rules as for base classes. And those old rules are far from perfect, in the history you can find arguments like "it is easier to implement it that way", "the layout algorithm would be a bit slower that way", etc, which would likely be done differently now, but are not considered worth the cost of breaking the ABI. To answer the question, yes, the standard allows compilers to do better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of `[[no_unique_address]]` is always at the discretion of the compiler; it is never required to do anything. A compiler can ignore it in all cases, respect it in some and ignore it in others, or respect it all the time. So long as the compiler is not doing it at random (ie: it's consistent), it can do whatever it wants (within the other rules of layout).

So why does it work in one case and not the other? Because that's how the compiler vendor implemented it.

If you want to take the best advantage of it, make things easiest for the compiler to handle. Don't use the same empty type multiple times (this limits what compilers can do). Declare all of the empty fields first.

Alternatively, you'll have to track down the ABI rules your compiler is using. The [Itanium ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) used on Linux has particular provisions for `no_unique_address`.